# Three things I don't understand about this javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

Hey I'm new to JavaScript and i was just wondering about some bit of code I never saw be for and i was just wondering how it worked to practice my JavaScript I wanted to make a calculator and I got this code online i was just wondering three things.

1. How does the code know to output the number and the answer into the text box.
2. How does this line of code work? `Calc.Input.value` I know that `Calc` is the form `Input` is well the Input and `value` is the value of the input like 1 2 or 3 but how does in know what input I'm choosing?
3. What exactly does `Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)` do and how does it work?

Thanks for your time and have a nice day and sorry if I didn't give enough info.

```
<FORM NAME="Calc">
<TABLE BORDER=4>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="text"   NAME="Input" Size="16">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one"   VALUE="  1  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '1'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="two"   VALUE="  2  " OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '2'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="three" VALUE="  3  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '3'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="plus"  VALUE="  +  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' + '">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="four"  VALUE="  4  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '4'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="five"  VALUE="  5  " OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '5'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="six"   VALUE="  6  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '6'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="minus" VALUE="  -  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' - '">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="seven" VALUE="  7  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '7'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="eight" VALUE="  8  " OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '8'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="nine"  VALUE="  9  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '9'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="times" VALUE="  x  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' * '">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" VALUE="  c  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value = ''">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="zero"  VALUE="  0  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '0'">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="DoIt"  VALUE="  =  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="div"   VALUE="  /  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' / '">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. see your `onClick` attribute: if it's clicked, execute the code in the `onClick`. The actual value of the input is only modified with these `+=` (append to). (If your current input is `6 +` and you click `4`, then `4` will be appended: it is now `6 + 4`)
2. `Input` is here also equivalent to the `name` attribute of your first input, that's why it's chosen.
3. `eval(Calc.Input.value)` is interpreting the value of your input as Javascript. So when there would be `4 + 6` in the input, it'll be evaluated as Javascript and return `10`.